# Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to run this query with multiple joins to get exact row as I want but I keep getting this error

> Not unique table/alias: 'ss_prices'

The query I'm running:

```
select `ss_accounts`.`id`, 
       `ss_accounts`.`bot_acc_id`, 
       `ss_accounts_inventories`.*, 
       `ss_prices`.* 
    from `ss_accounts_inventories` 
        left join `ss_prices` 
            on `ss_accounts_inventories`.`item_name` = `ss_prices`.`item_name` 
        left join `ss_prices` 
            on `ss_accounts_inventories`.`phase` = `ss_prices`.`item_phase` 
        inner join `ss_accounts` 
            on `ss_accounts_inventories`.`bot_id` = `ss_accounts`.`id` 
    order by `ss_prices`.`item_price` DESC
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't instead need a single join that uses multiple _conditions_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're joining the same table twice:

```
...
left join `ss_prices` on ...
left join `ss_prices` on ...
...
```

So anywhere else in the query when you reference that table, the query engine has no way to know *which one* you mean.  For example, in your `select` clause:

```
`ss_prices`.*
```

Give each joined table an alias so you can distinguish them:

```
...
left join `ss_prices` as item_name_prices on ...
left join `ss_prices` as phase_prices on ...
...
```

Then reference them by their aliases in the rest of the query:

```
select
  `ss_accounts`.`id`,
  `ss_accounts`.`bot_acc_id`,
  `ss_accounts_inventories`.*,
  `item_name_prices`.*, -- here
  `phase_prices`.* -- and here, etc.
```

Comment: also after using this method I faced another error - instead of receiving one row I get multiple same rows..

Comment: @Sandra: Then there are multiple records matching your query.  You can filter results with a "where" clause in SQL.

Comment: @Sandra: Nobody here can see your data.  But if you're getting multiple results then your query matches multiple things.  Select more of the data to see potential differences.  Your joins may also be duplicating data if they match on multiple rows.